# Information on the fact that the command is terminated, Shell in C

Tags: c, sh, fork

runcommand() serves to execute a command in a shell through `fork()`.

For the commands launched in the background, how can I print information on the fact that the command is terminated (using the WNOHANG option of the waitpid)?

Printed information: process terminated [PID]

It is important that all child processes end completely

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>  // tipi di apertura file
#include <assert.h> // assert
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define EOL 1       /* end of line */
#define ARG 2       /* normal topic */
#define AMPERSAND 3     /* & */
#define SEMICOLON 4 /* ; */
#define REDIRECT 5  /* > */
#define APPEND 6     /* >> */

#define MAXARG 512  /* maximum number of arguments */
#define MAXBUF 512

#define FOREGROUND 0
#define BACKGROUND 1

int gettok(char **outptr);  /* reads a symbol */
void runcommand(char **cline,int where);    /* execute a command */
int inarg(char c);      /* check if c is not a special character */

pid_t pid;

char prompt[MAXBUF];

static char inpbuf[MAXBUF], tokbuf[2*MAXBUF], *ptr, *tok;

static char special[]=
{' ', '\t', '&', ';', '\n', '\0', '>'};

int proc(void)  /* treats a line of input */
{
    char *arg[MAXARG+1];    /* array of pointers for runcommand */
    int toktype;
    int n_arg;      /* number of topics considered so far */
    int type;       /* FOREGROUND o BACKGROUND */

    n_arg=0;

    while (1)
    {
        switch (toktype = gettok(&arg[n_arg])) 
        {
            /* if argument: go to the next symbol */
            case ARG:

            if (n_arg < MAXARG)
                {n_arg++;}
                break;

            /* if end of line or ';' or '&' executes the command now contained in arg, putting NULL to signal the end of the arguments: it serves as execvp */
            case EOL:
            case SEMICOLON:
            case AMPERSAND:
            type = (toktype == AMPERSAND) ? BACKGROUND : FOREGROUND;

            if (n_arg != 0) 
            {
                arg[n_arg] = NULL;
                runcommand(arg,type);
            }


            if (toktype == EOL) return 1;

            n_arg = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void runcommand(char **command,int wr)  
{
    int exitstat,ret;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == (pid_t) -1) 
    {
        perror("smallsh: fork fallita");
        return;
    }
    if (pid == (pid_t) 0)           /* child */
    {
        execvp(*command,command);/* executes a command */
        perror(*command);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(wr != BACKGROUND)    /* father */
    {
        ret = waitpid(pid, &exitstat, 0);
        if (ret == -1) perror("wait");
    }
}

int scan(char *p); /* print the prompt and read a line */

int main()
{
    while(scan(prompt) != EOF)
    proc();
}

int scan(char *p)
{
    int c, count;

    ptr = inpbuf;
    tok = tokbuf;

    printf("%s ",p);

    count=0;

    while(1) 
    {

        if ((c = getchar()) == EOF)
            return(EOF);

        if (count < MAXBUF)
            inpbuf[count++] = c;

        if (c == '\n' && count < MAXBUF) 
        {
            inpbuf[count] = '\0';
            return(count);
        }
        if (c == '\n') 
        {
            printf("riga in input troppo lunga\n");
            count = 0;
            printf("%s ",p);
        }
    }
}

int gettok(char **outptr)  
{
    int type;
    *outptr = tok;
    while (*ptr == ' ' || *ptr == '\t') ptr++;
    *tok++ = *ptr;
    switch(*ptr++)
    {
        case '\n':
        type = EOL; break;
        case '&':
        type = AMPERSAND; break;
        case ';':
        type = SEMICOLON; break;
        default:
        type = ARG;
        while(inarg(*ptr))
        *tok++ = *ptr++;
    }
    *tok++ = '\0';
    return(type);
}

int inarg(char c)  
{
    char *wrk;
    for (wrk = special; *wrk != '\0'; wrk++)
    if (c == *wrk) return(0);
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe your use case in more detail and add some background information. I assume you want to implement a small shell in contrast to using a shell. Do you want to implement a different function that checks if a background process has terminated? What information do you want to print? (Maybe you need a table to store the `PID` of the background process and the corresponding command.) Is it sufficient to do this check only when the shell prints a new prompt? Or do you need it asynchronously while entering or executing other commands?

Comment: Do you want to implement a different function that checks if a background process has terminated? 
I would rather not.                                

What information do you want to print? (Maybe you need a table to store the PID of the background process and the corresponding command.) 
the PID could be useful if you get it from getpid (). I don't need a table to store PIDs.                      

Is it sufficient to do this check only when the shell prints a new prompt? Or do you need it asynchronously while entering or executing other commands?
I need it asynchronously.

Comment: You can't do it in that function — you need the main shell command execution loop to check for finished background processes, or set up a SIGCHLD handler that sets a flag to tell the main loop to process a child that died, or something similar.

Comment: @Exclamativo As I already wrote in my previous comment, please [edit] your question to add more information instead of answering in comments. As Jonathan Leffler wrote it is not possible to do this in function `runcommand`. You have to show more details of your shell implementation. (SW architecture, more code) to get suggestions.

Comment: You can't wait for child processes to terminate without waiting for them to terminate.  The question seems circular.

Comment: If you want the notification while running other commands, you would have to do it while waiting for foreground commands to terminate or while waiting for user input. You probably need loops and signal handling in all these program parts. You should specify what exactly you want to have printed when a background process terminates.

Comment: Please use the shell tag for questions where expertise in the POSIX sh specification assists in answering. This should just be tagged `c`; that what you're implementing in C is a toy shell is irrelevant for purposes of answering the question.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I think we can manage through a third process

Comment: @Bodo Should I use a third process?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What would the code of loop to check for finished background processes or SIGCHLD handler, using WNOHANG?

Comment: `while (1) { check_dead_processes(); prompt(); if (read_cmd(&cmdstr, &cmdlen) == EOF) break; if (parse_cmd(cmdstr, cmdlen, &cmdlst) == 0) execute_cmd(cmdlst); }` or thereabouts, guessing at various names that might be relevant.  The `check_dead_processes()` function would contain a loop with `waitpid()` and `WNOHANG` and would look for any dead children, stopping when `waitpid()` returns with "no more dead children at the moment".  There are endless details to be resolved; you might need some PID lists and so on  and so forth.  Somewhere, you'd record history.  And so on.

Comment: @Exclamativo You don't need an additional process. If you already have running background processes when you run a foreground process, you can use `waitpid` in a loop to wait for any process and also handle background processes until your foreground process terminates. If your shell doesn't currently run a foreground process and waits for command input, probably using `read`, you can handle signal SIGCHLD which will result in read returning a value `<0` and `EINTR`. Then you can run `waitpid` with `WHOHANG` in a loop to wait for all children that may have terminated, then repeat the `read`.

Comment: @Exclamativo It is impossible to give better suggestions without knowing more details about the software architecture of your shell. (Which functions do you have for what purpose? How do they call each other? ...)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how to look for any dead child processes with waitpid () and WNOHANG?

Comment: Read the POSIX specification of [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html); look at the options for the `pid` (first) argument.  You need to ensure that you can find the manual pages on your system, or on the internet (`man7.org`, `linux.die.net`, the POSIX spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Answer (score 0):

So if you call `ret = waitpid(pid, &exitstat, WNOHANG)`, then the command will return even if the child did not exit. Hence you need to look at the returned value `ret` to see if the function was successful and then the value of `exitstat` to see if the child has exited (either by returning from the `main()` function or due to a signal):

```
if(ret >= 0)
{
    if(WIFEXITED(exitstat) || WIFSIGNALED(exitstat))
    {
        printf("Child ended\n");
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Error!\n");
}
```

Note:

1. In some cases, you may also want to check `WIFSTOPPED(exitstat)`. See [waitpid(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) for details.
2. In case of error, you may check [errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) for further information about what went wrong.

Comment: You need to look at `errno` to know what happened if `ret` is negative (`-1`) on return from `waitpid()`.  If `ret` is negative, the value in `exitstat` is indeterminate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right and it is generally important to put attention on code that is robust to other scenarios than the one where everything goes smooth. I have tried to update the answer accordingly. Thanks for noticing this.